# Is it possible to incorporate Angular into an existing .NET MVVM Project?

Tags: c#, .net, angular, mvvm

I have a project that doesn't have a real front-end, but rather razor views sitting on top of an application and interacting with it's view model to access data. I'd like to use Angular with my existing project to componentize some of the repeated code to save myself time and maintainability.

Is this possible without rewriting all of my views?

Comment: You are using MVVM in an MVC project? Wow, that's the first time I read that

Comment: Can you add some examples of what you have? Maybe you have MVC project, not MVVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can gradually move it over one page at a time. Make an angular app and make it handle one of the full pages. When that loads it can act as an SPA and when you need to access other pages link out like normal. Then gradually move other pages into the SPA as needed.

The users will need to load Angular multiple times which reduces the benefit of an SPA, but with caching and a proper CDN this should not be a big concern.

Comment: This would also require me to create APIs for all of the data I need from the application right? I realize this is probably not possible, but what I'm kind of hoping for is the ability to create angular components and then render them inside of razor without having to create an API layer.

Comment: That's really not going to work well. It's possible if you want to use Angular just for rendering, but you're definitely using wrong tool there. You might be more interested in React which really is just a component rendering engine, but if you want to stick to traditional models of handling data then stick to traditional html rendering as well.

Comment: Why would you consider that to be the wrong tool? In my (limited) experience using Angular, it seemed like a great way to create reusable components.

Perhaps my understanding of the strengths of angular is wrong. Also, thanks for answering my questions :-)

Comment: @smooth_atonal_sound I feel like Angular is overkill for just components, but I'm also used to building full applications with services and everything. Certainly it's just my opinion so if it works for you, go for it.